# Using partitionBy and coalesce together in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write data to s3 based on a particular `Partition` key, this I can easily do by using `write.partitionBy`. However, in this case I need to write only one file in each path. I am using the below code to do this.

```
    orderFlow.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("SellerYearMonthWeekKey")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(outputS3Path + "/")
```

Can you please help me with the best approach to achieve this? I am getting OutOfMemmory errors in the above case.

Comment: The problem is that your partition does not fit in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to output a single file per partition you can repartition the dataset by the same column used in `partitionBy`

```
   orderFlow.repartition("SellerYearMonthWeekKey")
      .write.partitionBy("SellerYearMonthWeekKey")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(outputS3Path + "/")
```

This will cost you a shuffle but guarantees a single file per partition directory.

Comment: What about performance, if it increases shuffle, I will end up with OutOfMemory errors again.

Comment: No, because your partitions will be correctly split among all the executors whereas your coalesce(1) tries to channel all the data on a single executor. If your data is heavily skewed you may have some memory issues but otherwise you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can help you -

```
object Stackoverflow1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").master("local").getOrCreate()

    val rdd = orderFlow.rdd.map(a => (a.getAs[String]("SellerYearMonthWeekKey"),a.toSeq.mkString(",")))

    val outputPath = "<S3_Location>"

      rdd.saveAsHadoopFile(outputPath, classOf[String], classOf[String],
      classOf[CustomMultipleTextOutputFormat])


  }

  class CustomMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
    override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any =
      NullWritable.get()

    override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String =
      key.asInstanceOf[String]
  }

}
```